# fgets equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, fgets

What is the C++ equivalent to the C function `fgets`?

I have looked at `getline` from `ifstream`, but when it comes to an end of line character, `'\n'`, it terminates at and discards it. I am looking for a function that just terminates at the end line character but adds the end of line character to the `char` array.

Comment: The `fgets` function is still valid in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `std::getline()`; just append the newline character yourself.  For example,

```
std::ifstream fs("filename.txt");
std::string s;
std::getline(fs, s);

// Make sure we didn't reach the end or fail before reading the delimiter:
if (fs)
    s.push_back('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the line terminator there by hand afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just use C++'s getline and add the newline on yourself.